# Using text3D in ribbon plot in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, ribbon

I want to construct a 3D ribbon plot with the following data.

```
    structure(c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 21, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 21, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 19, 
10, 10, 10, 21, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
20, 10, 20, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 21, 9, 9, 9, 18, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 19, 9, 8, 8, 16, 8, 16, 8, 21, 20, 8, 8, 16, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 18, 8, 8, 19, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 21, 20, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 19, 9, 9, 18, 9, 8, 8, 16, 8, 16, 8, 21, 20, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 19, 8, 8, 18, 8, 7, 7, 14, 7, 16, 7, 21, 20, 7, 
18, 7, 7, 7, 7, 14, 7, 19, 7, 7, 16, 7, 8, 8, 16, 8, 8, 8, 20, 
19, 8, 21, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 8, 18, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 8, 8, 
8, 20, 19, 16, 21, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 8, 18, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 17, 
8, 16, 8, 20, 18, 8, 21, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 8, 18, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 
7, 16, 16, 16, 7, 18, 20, 7, 21, 16, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 19, 7, 7, 
7, 7), .Dim = c(21L, 12L), .Dimnames = list(c("colmA", "colmB", 
"colmC", "colmD", "colmE", "colmF", "colmG", "colmH", "colmI", 
"colmJ", "colmK", "colmL", "colmM", "colmN", "colmO", "colmP", 
"colmQ", "colmR", "colmS", "colmT", "colmU"), c("2005", "2006", 
"2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", 
"2015", "2016")))
```

I have to work out a code in the meanwhile as I did not get any response. Here is the code.

```
ribbon3D(x = 1:21, y = 1:12, z = tf14, scale = T, expand = 0.01, bty = "g", along = "y",  
         col = "pink", border = "black", shade = 0.2, ltheta = -90, lphi = 30, space = 0.5, 
         ticktype = "detailed", d = 2, curtain = T, xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "")


# Use text3D to label x axis
text3D(x = 1:21, y = rep(0.5, 21), z = rep(1, 21),
       labels = rownames(tf14),
       add = TRUE, adj = 0, lphi = 30, ltheta = -90)

# Use text3D to label y axis
text3D(x = rep(0.5, 12), y = 1:12, z = rep(1, 12),
       labels  = colnames(tf14),
       add = TRUE, adj = 1, lphi = 30, ltheta = -90)
```

But, the image that I get is not the desired one. The axis labels are cluttered and the side on which years are displayed needs to be right hand side. Also, the height of the ribbons is too low.[image: the image of ribbon 3d]

Can somebody improve the code?

Comment: thanks for making it better, waiting for guidance.

Comment: height of the ribbon can be handled if we use `scale = FALSE`.